# Brackets editor and "Node.js: Server-side Javascript" taking all processing power

Tags: javascript, node.js, adobe-brackets, overheating

I have been using the Brackets editor for writing html- and js-files and testing them in Chrome with the live preview (having a server and using localhost, whatever the inner-workings of that is).

Recently this process called "node.exe *32", "Node.js: Server-side Javascript" has been running and taking up all the processing power (or 50% but I guess it's only because it uses one core(?)). Of course this makes the program totally unusable because in the long run it will heat up my laptop and perhaps destroy it permanently (luckily I have Core-Temp that will warn me when it overheats if I don't notice it).

The process won't shut off even when I close the editor and I have to kill it from the manager. Sometimes the things I'm doing in Brackets won't work when I kill it (and try and continue to use Brackets) but for example now that I tested everything seems ok even after killing the node.exe process.

What is causing this and how to stop it? Or what would be some other editors where I can write html, css and js files and test them in Chrome with a push of a button?

**EDIT** Again the program won't work after the process is killed and now the process even seems to be reborn whenever I kill it. It must be a **virus of the most malicious kind**???

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" it myself by renaiming node.exe in the Brackets folder to something else. Now it won't run but at least the live preview still works. Don't know if xhttpxml-requests or that sort of cross-origin -stuff will work but it's OK for now if I don't use them.

Oh, it's just the file://... in the address bar so it's like not running the server I assume, so it's the same thing that I just opened the file to Chrome "as is". Well, at least I can now use the editor.

Still would like to know some answers.